# Determine if given OS name is server-based or desktop-based

Tags: java, server, operating-system

My java based application is installed in a number of Users' computer. During the first run, it automatically sends the user's OS name to my server and is stored in database. I used `System.getProperty("os.name");` to get the user's Operating System name in that application. Is that possible to determine if that is a Server based Computer(Windows Server 2012 Standard) or Desktop Computer(Ubuntu, Windows 7)?

Is there any possible way to determine between Server and Desktop Computer with Java?

Comment: Why would `System.getProperty("os.name")` give you the user's OS?

Comment: @melpomene I need to know the type of computer(desktop/server) he uses!

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. You're just repeating what you said in your post.

Comment: It gives the user's OS name. That's the default behaviour in jvm!

Comment: No, it doesn't. It gives you the OS name of the web server.

Comment: @melpomene seems you've understood in different context. I've edited the question more clearly

Answer (score 3):

> I use `System.getProperty("os.name");` in a Java based web application to get the user's Operating System name.

That gets you the operating system name of the server that's running the web application, not the user's computer.

You can try to extract operating system information from the browser's User-Agent header, but this is inherently an error-prone process. Moreover, Microsoft Windows is the only operating system that has a clear server/desktop distinction of the sort you're looking for; Linux and macOS do not have any such distinction.

Comment: Error-prone _and insecure_, if you're using it for anything like input validation, enforcing a license, etc. As with any and all input you get from client calls, you should assume it's lying unless you can prove otherwise. Headers are very easy to spoof or change.

Comment: OS name is not sent through Header like web app. The application is standalone and makes a POST request to server!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possible way to determine between Server and Desktop Computer with Java?

(Assuming that you can get the value of the "os.name" property for the relevant machine.)

The answer is there isn't a reliable way.

For a start, there is no hard distinction between a server and desktop computer.  I can take a headless server installation of Linux and turn it into a desktop Linux simply by installing a few packages.  The OS doesn't change, the distribution doesn't change, and the string in the "os.name" property won't change.

The best you can do is to figure out common patterns for "os.name" strings on various **common** Java + OS platforms.   But that will be fragile, at best.